# Adding ImageIcon to JDialog, file path exception

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm trying to create a JLabel using an ImageIcon, but am having trouble reading the original png from disk. Here is how I have my project set up:

The .java file I'm working with (AboutJDialog) is here:
[image: :]

And here is where I store my image:
[image]

According to my understanding, the following code should be working (this is just a snippet obviously, just looking at the filepath right now):

```
image = new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MergeHero.IMAGE/dynamsoft_logo_black.png")))); //imports the image

JLabel lbl = new JLabel(image); //puts the image into a jlabel

this.getContentPane().add(lbl);
```

Comment: try using `/MergeHero/IMAGE/dynamsoft_logo_black.png`

Comment: Try removing the first forward slash from "/MergeHero.IMAGE/dynamsoft_logo_black.png". If you're on a UNIX based system, that's likely to be the root of the file system.

Comment: @user432 Great! That fixed the problem. Unfortunately I'm now having trouble getting the image to display, but I guess that's an issue for a separate question.